# Searching through the elements of a map in c++

Tags: c++, stl, maps, composition

The Question is as follows: Create 2 classes Students, Subjects and enter their data members as Maps and interconnect them using Composition.The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class student {
public:
    map<int, string> student_map;

    student()
    {
        student_map[100] = "  Noel Philip";
        student_map[101] = "  John";
        student_map[102] = "  Jerry";
        student_map[103] = "  James";
    }

    void display_details_Engineering()
    {
        for (map<int, string>::iterator itr = student_map.begin(); ((itr->first) == 100) || ((itr->first) == 101); ++itr) {
            cout << "ROll NO" << itr->first << "  Name" << itr->second << endl;
        }
    }

    void display_details_Medicine()

    {
        for (map<int, string>::iterator itr = student_map.begin(); ((itr->first) == 102) || ((itr->first) == 103); ++itr) {
            cout << "ROll NO" << itr->first << "  Name" << itr->second << endl;
        }
    }

    void display_alldetails()
    {
        for (map<int, string>::iterator itr = student_map.begin(); itr != student_map.end(); ++itr) {
            cout << "ROll NO" << itr->first << "  Name" << itr->second << endl;
        }
    }

    ~student(){};
};

class subjects {

public:
    map<string, int> eng_subjects;

    map<string, int> medicine_subjects;

    subjects()
    {
        eng_subjects["  Engineering Physics"] = 90;
        eng_subjects["  Engineering Chemistry"] = 80;
        medicine_subjects["  Zoology"] = 90;
        medicine_subjects["  Humanology"] = 80;
    }

    void display_details_Engineering()
    {
        for (map<string, int>::iterator itr = eng_subjects.begin(); itr != eng_subjects.end(); ++itr) {
            cout << "Subject Name" << itr->first << "  Grades" << itr->second << endl;
        }
        s1.display_details_Engineering();
    }

    void display_details_Medicine()
    {
        for (map<string, int>::iterator itr = medicine_subjects.begin(); itr != medicine_subjects.end(); ++itr) {
            cout << "Subject Name" << itr->first << "  Grades" << itr->second << endl;
        }
        s1.display_details_Medicine();
    }
    ~subjects(){};

    //  void display_details_Engineering()      Not Required
    //{
    //s1.display_details_Engineering();
    //}
private:
    student s1;
};

int main()
{
    student s;

    s.display_alldetails();
    s.display_details_Engineering();
    s.display_details_Medicine();

    subjects sub;
    sub.display_details_Engineering();
    sub.display_details_Medicine();
}
```

The output is as follows

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

ROll NO102  Name  Jerry

ROll NO103  Name  James

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

Subject Name  Engineering Chemistry  Grades80

Subject Name  Engineering Physics  Grades90

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

Subject Name  Humanology  Grades80

Subject Name  Zoology  Grades90

***When the required output is:***

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

ROll NO102  Name  Jerry

ROll NO103  Name  James

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

ROll NO102  Name  Jerry

ROll NO103  Name  James

Subject Name  Engineering Chemistry  Grades80.

Subject Name  Engineering Physics  Grades90

ROll NO100  Name  Noel Philip

ROll NO101  Name  John

Subject Name  Humanology  Grades80

Subject Name  Zoology  Grades90

ROll NO102  Name  Jerry

ROll NO103  Name  James

Comment: "The Question is as follows:" ... that is not a question, but an assignment.

Comment: what is wrong with the output you get? Maybe there is some difference to what it should be, but I cant spot the difference

Comment: @tobi303 required has extra lines

Comment: Try stepping through the code, possibly on a smaller input, and try to figure out which lines you think might be wrong :-)

Comment: @tobi303 Rookie over here. Do excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look closely, but in your "for" loop the middle expression is not a filter, if it doesn't evaluate to boolean true then the for loop stops. So in "display_details_Medicine()", as soon as the itr->first doesn't equal 102 or 103 the loop ends.

Do your comparisons within the body of the methods.  Or better yet, create an array of the values for each set and iterate through each set, which is far more efficient than reading every member of the map and selecting only the ones that you want.

Answer (score 0):

**@rabinnh is correct. For `display_details_Engineering()` and `display_details_Medicine()`, check for condition within the loop.**

The code below should work correctly.

```
void display_details_Engineering()
{
    for (map<int, string>::iterator itr = student_map.begin(); itr != student_map.end(); ++itr) {
        if (itr->first == 100 || itr->first == 101)
            cout << "ROll NO" << itr->first << "  Name" << itr->second << endl;
    }
}

void display_details_Medicine()

{
    for (map<int, string>::iterator itr = student_map.begin(); itr != student_map.end(); ++itr) {
        if (itr->first == 102 || itr->first == 103)
            cout << "ROll NO" << itr->first << "  Name" << itr->second << endl;
    }
}
```

**You are using `std::map` which is ordered by key.**

In `display_details_Medicine()` you want to print keys `102` and `103`. However, your for loop first sees the key `100`, which fails the loop condition, ending the loop without printing anything.